# how to remove default onclick and active effects of a button in internet explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

in internet explorer 9 when clicking on buttons with the html:

```
<fieldset class="this_fieldset">
<p style="display:inline">title:</p>
<button class="styled_buttons" data-filter=".1">all</button>
<button class="styled_buttons" data-filter=".1.2">2</button>
<button class="styled_buttons" data-filter=".1.3">3</button>
<button class="styled_buttons" data-filter=".1.4">4</button>
<button class="styled_buttons" data-filter=".1.5">5</button>
<button class="styled_buttons" data-filter=".1.6">6</button>
<button class="styled_buttons" data-filter=".1.7">7</button>
</fieldset>
```

the text on the button shifts and a border appears (and stays) on the button.

how can i remove these effects (they are not appearing in chrome and ff).

thank you.

update: current css as requested:

```
fieldset.this_fieldset {
float: left;
}
```

and

```
.styled_buttons {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 23px;
padding: 2px 10px;
}

/* for firefox only */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.styled_buttons {
padding: 2px 5px;
}
}

.styled_buttons:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Try setting "* { outline:none; }"

Comment: Provide the css for at the very least styled_buttons and this_fieldset classes

Comment: @Billy Too bad one can't downvote comments...

Comment: @drk please see updated post with css, thank you.

Comment: @Christoph - I humbly apologise for my ill thought out and downright stupid comment. I'll just go and give myself 20 lashes.